# Having trouble creating a polygon using mouse clicks in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, mouseevent, polygon

I'm trying to create a javafx program that allows the user to click a draw button and create polygons by clicking on various points on a pane. When the user double clicks the polygon is created

So what I have so far is:

```
X1 = event.getX();      // x position where mouse was pressed
Y1 = event.getY();      // y position where mouse was pressed

if(mode == mode.DRAW){  //sets the mode to draw
    Polygon currentPolygon = new Polygon();   //creates new polygon

    while(event.getClickCount() !=2){      //checks if double click has happened
        currentPolygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{X1,Y1});        //adds the x and y values of the spot clicked 
        currentPolygon.setFill(new Color(1, 1, 1, 0));   //makes empty fill
        currentPolygon.setStroke(Color.RED);             //creates red stroke
        drawPane.getChildren().add(currentPolygon);    //adds it to my drawPane
    }
}
```

My biggest problem is figuring out how to get the click input to load the points clicked into my polygon

Comment: Add each mouse input to a collection such as `List<Point2D>`.Add points from this list to the `Polygon`. For more help post [mre].

Comment: _Somewhat unrelated:_ I suspect the `while (event.getClickCount() != 2)` will cause an infinite loop, consequently making your UI become unresponsive.